# "Not Found" error occurred while trying to fetch "NumberOfEnabledCore" value from "Win32_Processor" class of WMI

Tags: wmi

I am trying to extract "**NumberOfEnabledCore**" value from "**Win32_Processor**" class of WMI. When I have executed "**Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Processor | Select ***" in Powershell in **Windows 8.1**, I am getting error as "Not Found". 
However, when I ran the same script in **Windows 10**, I am getting value for "NumberOfEnabledCore".
Can someone please assist on this WMI script behavior?

Thanks. 
Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: *This property is not supported before Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview and Windows 10.* from that page you referenced ...

Comment: Yes, I did see that line "Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Vista:  This property is not supported before Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview and Windows 10.". However, its confusing; why all the OSs listed here and in the next line its written that its not support below Win 10...

Comment: It tries to convey the message that for these OS's there are special conditions to be aware of. In this case they tell you it is not supported. It is their documentation style.